# How to fix 'argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA'

Tags: r

Ive read in my excel data and found the max value for each column and calculated the mean from that.

```
library(readxl)
exp4 <- read_excel("exp4.xlsx")
View(exp4)
```

## this gives you the highest value in the entire datase

```
maxpeak <- apply(exp4, MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE))
maxpeak
#the mean of all the max peaks in this experiment
mean16052019exp4 <- mean(maxpeak)
mean16052019exp4
```

I've then taken the original max value and subtracted the baseline values using another excel spreadsheet read in BUT when i now want the mean of these new values:

```
realmaxpeak <- (maxpeak - exp4baseline)
realmaxpeak
#trying to calculate the mean of the baseline adjusted values
View(realmaxpeak)
mean(realmaxpeak)
```

I get: Warning message:

> In mean.default(realmaxpeak[0.1]) :   argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

Why can i not calculate the mean from the vector (realmaxpeak) i created?

TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which is the result of `class(realmaxpeak)`? This should address you, with reading `?mean`, on what is not going well.

Comment: > class(realmaxpeak)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: apply(realmaxpeak, 1, mean)   this seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the summary of the data in realmaxpeak? It could not be recognizing the field as a numeric field. If this is the case, you would utilize as.numeric()

Comment: > realmaxpeak
      cell 1    cell 2     cell 3      cell 4     cell 5    cell 6     cell 7
1 0.06008397 0.5322739 -0.1750701 -0.06291132 -0.4149553 -0.184212

Comment: it runs on like this up to cell 40

Comment: apply(realmaxpeak, 1, mean)
 this seems to have done the trick?